# Why isn't the cursive font working with Cascadia Code in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Cascadia Code cursive font doesn't work in VS Code. I installed the latest version of CascadiaCode.ttf but cursive font doesn't work there is only italic font.

My VS Code `settings.json`:

```
{
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Cascadia Code', Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.fontSize": 18,
  "window.zoomLevel": 2,
  "editor.fontLigatures": "'calt', 'ss01'",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Monokai Vibrant",
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "comments": {"fontStyle": "italic"}
  },
  "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
}
```

[My VS Code setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DlPC.png)

Comment: It's clearly working, because the rest of the window looks fine.  You just need to turn off "italic" for keywords and parameter names, if you don't want that.

Comment: @TimRoberts i know but i want it to look like this :

https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--eK2VHHyC--/c_imagga_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,h_900,q_auto,w_1600/https://dev-to-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/articles/863vu5vue47g3q6zp6wo.png

Comment: NOW I understand your issue.  Did you install CascadiaCodeItalic.ttf?  That's where the italic glyphs live.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes you right !! i installed it now and it fixes the issue, thank you very much sir and god bless your family

Answer (score 0):

add this to you settings.json

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
            "comment",
            "entity.name.type.class", //class names
            "entity.other.attribute-name", //HTML Attributes
            "keyword", //import, export, return…
            "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
            "storage.modifier", //static keyword
            "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
            ],
            "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        },
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer.